# Avoiding unnecessary template instantiations in a fluent interface

Tags: c++, performance, templates, fluent-interface

I have a class with some optional template parameters:

```
struct option1_default_t {};
struct option2_default_t {};

template <typename T, 
          typename option1_t = option1_default_t, 
          typename option2_t = option2_default_t>
class foo
{
public:
    foo(option1_t option1 = option1_t(), option2_t option2 = option2_t());

    void run();
};
```

And the following [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) for specifying them:

```
template <typename T, typename option1_t, typename option2_t>
struct foo_runner
{
    option1_t option1_;
    option2_t option2_;

    template <typename new_option1_t>
    foo_runner<T, new_option1_t, option2_t> option1(new_option1_t new_option1)
    {
        return foo_runner<T, new_option1_t, option2_t>{new_option1, option2_};
    }

    template <typename new_option2_t>
    foo_runner<T, option1_t, new_option2_t> option2(new_option2_t new_option2)
    {
        return foo_runner<T, option1_t, new_option2_t>{option1_, new_option2};
    }

    void run()
    {
        foo<T, option1_t, option2_t> f(option1_, option2_);
        f.run();
    }
};

template <typename T>   
foo_runner<T, option1_default_t, option2_default_t> make_foo()
{
    return foo_runner<T, option1_default_t, option2_default_t>();
}
```

Here's an example of how the fluent interface is used:

```
struct my_option1_t { ... };
struct my_option2_t { ... };

int main()
{
    make_foo<int>()
        .option1(my_option1_t(...))
        .option2(my_option2_t(...))
        .run();
}
```

This is of course a simplified version; in my real code there are many options, and in a typical use of this class, only a few of them are specified, hence the justification for the fluent interface.

The problem with this fluent interface is that it incurs unnecessary template instantiations. For example, the example above instantiates `foo` three times: `foo<int, option1_default_t, option2_default_t>`, `foo<int, my_option1_t, option2_default_t>`, and finally, `foo<int, my_option1_t, my_option2_t>`, which is the one I want.

This is problematic because `foo` is a big class and instantiating it is compile-time expensive.

Is there a way I could change the implementation of the fluent interface **without changing how the interface is used** so that `foo` is only instantiated once, with the final arguments?

Please note that the requirement that the interface does not change - i.e. that the exact same code that I gave as an example of using the fluent interface, continues to work unchanged - is key here. Without that requirement I could easily rewrite the fluent interface to only instantiate `foo` once (for example I could change the interface to be something like `run_foo(make_foo<int>().option1(...).option2(...))`).

Comment: Are you sure that this template instantiations is the bottleneck?

Comment: Are you even sure there are 3 instances of `foo` instantiated? I can't see why they would be. I only see an instantiation from `foo_runner<int, my_option1_t, my_option2_t>::run()`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there are multiple instantiations of `foo` (as was pointed out in the comment by MSalters). If you want to verify this, you can create specializations of `foo` for the defaulted parameters which would cause an error when they are instantiated. Obviously, this wouldn't be good for the actual production version but this would prove that there aren't multiple instantiations.

Once you verified that multiple instantiations of `foo` are indeed not the problem, the question becomes: how to improve compile times for templated code? The answer to this is, generally, to factor the code into helpers which depend on fewer template arguments (if any). It is somewhat of a pain but can have a dramatic impact. It may also be beneficial to avoid instantiation in all translation units of commonly used templates. With C++2011 you can use extern templates combined with explicit instantiations. With C++2003 you'd have to specialize the code you want to preinstantiate.

Comment: You're right, there are no multiple instantiations of `foo` in the code above... something went wrong in the process of reducing my actual code (which did have multiple instantiations of `foo`, as evident from the fact that I got an error message from within two different instantiations of `foo`) to this example. I will investigate.